# Pandas reads all columns into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, text-files

I am trying to load a txt file separated with semicolons ';', but when using pandas' read_csv it puts the two columns into a single column. The .txt file looks as follows:

```
Profile 1;Profile 1;
x;y;
[m];[m];
0;3.4467541e-010;
1.0053956e-007;3.5615887e-010;
2.0107912e-007;5.7246124e-010;
3.0161869e-007;6.8413124e-010;
4.0215825e-007;7.3333242e-010;
...
5.2280572e-006;1.9645013e-009;
5.3285968e-006;1.8215396e-009;
```

My attempt takes the form of:

```
df = pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', sep=';', header=2)
```

The output from this is:

```
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 54 entries, 0 to 53
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                --------------  -----
 0   [m]     [m]           54 non-null     object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 560.0+ bytes
```

I have also tried other ways with using "with open()", but with no luck either.

Comment: Have you tried to use the skiprows?

Comment: Maybe my question is stupid but what is `data` if your dataframe is `df`? Else your code works well here.

Comment: Trying "data = pd.read_csv(path_to_data + filename, sep=';', header=None, skiprows=3)" still yields only one column.

Comment: Yes, 'data' is 'df'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Reihaneh Kouhi reported the problem is the last semicolon creating an extra empty column and the first and the third row (to skip). 
I tried this locally and it should work. 
I just skip the rows and then delete the last column

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_csv("table.csv", sep=";",  skiprows=[0,2], skipinitialspace=True, engine='python')
table = table.iloc[:, :-1]
print(table)
```

Comment: This does the job! Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your separator is a semicolon, and after the second column you have another semicolon.
This is why this problem happens. Just get rid of the last semicolon in each row and run the code.
I am not sure, but this works for me.

Comment: @BigBen yes, I edit it. thanks :)

Comment: Is there a clever way to do that? The data is exported like this from a different software.

Comment: @Woodywoodleg please check if it works. If yes, then we will find a way. I am not expert in python, but we can find a way always :)

Comment: even after manually removing the las semicolon, the data still loads into a single column. But the solution proposed by Cr4zyTun4 seems to do the job! Thanks for the help.